# Salesforce displaying Time custom field in GMT instead of User's timezone

Tags: datetime, timezone, time

We are facing an issue with BST and GMT time zone.
We have a community portal and the org timezone and all the Users timezone are set as BST.
Part of our functionality is to book an event and we redirect our users (on the community portal) to a third party system which displays available slots in BST.

Once the user provides their detail and confirms their booking, this third party system then POSTS back into salesforce and create a record of our custom Event booking object.

The Event Booking object has a custom field Booking_Start_Time__c and Booking_End_Time__c.
The third party system, for an event booked for **9:00 AM to 9:30 AM**, send

```
{"Booking_Start_Time__c" : "08:00:00.000Z",
 "Booking_End_Time__c" : "08:30:00.000Z"}
```

Essentially, they are sending the GMT time (-1 for the actual booking time) for booking start and end times.
The issue is Salesforce displays this as is i.e. "08:00" and "08:30" on the Event Booking detail page even though the User's timezone is set as BST

I am unable to explain this behaviour and would appreciate if someone can shed some light on this.

Adding some screenshots

1. User time zone : [image]
2. Event booking display page : [image]
3. Same record when accessed in workbench : [image]

Answer (score 4):

All DateTimes in Salesforce are stored as GMT/UTC so that they can easily be shifted based on a user's timezone (a necessity in any organization where users are logging in from multiple time zones). So if you see GMT in the database, that's as designed. If the time isn't being shown properly to the *end user*, consider using a component that displays a DateTime based on a user's locale such as [formatted-date-time](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-date-time/example) in a LWC, or [lightning:formattedDateTime](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:formattedDateTime/example) in an Aura component. You can also render a DateTime in a specific timezone using the [`DateTime.format()` method in Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm) or a combination of `date()`, which returns the current date in the context of the running user, and `time()` which returns the current time in the context of the running user.

```java
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.newInstance(1999, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0);
System.debug('My User format (taking into account Locale and TimeZone): ' + myDateTime.format());
System.debug('Perth: ' + myDateTime.format('MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a z', 'Australia/Perth'));
System.debug('Seoul: ' + myDateTime.format('MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a z', 'Asia/Seoul'));
System.debug('Los Angeles: ' + myDateTime.format('MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a z', 'America/Los_Angeles'));
```

This outputs (I ran this as a user with an American locale and an EDT timezone):

```
My User format (taking into account Locale and TimeZone): 1/1/1999 1:00 AM
Perth: 01/01/1999 02:00:00 PM AWST
Seoul: 01/01/1999 03:00:00 PM KST
Los Angeles: 12/31/1998 10:00:00 PM PST
```

**EDIT**

I think I see the problem and it's my own inexperience with "Time" custom fields (they're relatively new) as opposed to "DateTime" custom fields. Time fields don't react to a user's location. That's because "11:00", "14:00", "12:50 AM" would all be valid inputs to a Time field and - without a date component - it's not possible to know if Daylight Savings Time is in effect or how far to shift a time based on where you are in the world. See [some of the notes from Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custom_field_time_overview.htm&type=5) regarding the Time field or [this Trailblazers post](https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000pY8lQAE). Relevant answer quoted below from Amnon Kruvi:

> Since the question is about Time fields, and not DateTime, the answer is no - they are not converted to a timezone.
> The reason for this is that timezones are date-dependent (thanks to daylight saving time). Hence, without an anchor to the date, it is not possible to convert a time between timezones.

If you *know* you will only ever need to support BST timezone (and Daylight Savings isn't a factor) and no one in the org will ever be another timezone, it's probably safe to set the timezone for the org to BST and use a Time field. However, if you need to support multiple timezones I would switch to using a DateTime field instead to accurately capture times.

Comment: Hi @nbrown, i am just curious why salesforce isnt showing the BST time on the objects detail page within salesforce. I can implement the lightning:formattedDateTime to fix this but based on Salesforce docs, i shouldnt have to

Comment: The object page should reflect the timezone of the user automatically. Can you double-check the timezone for the problem user?

Comment: Hi @nbrown, have attached screenshots of timezone, the booking time on detail page and what it shows in the backend.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the distinction between Time and DateTime in your post. Time is a relatively new field type that I've never used. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: What you say makes perfect sense. I just tested it with a date time field and it works. However, I still think Salesforce is doing some kind of timezone conversion for time fields. If I send time field without the Z i.e. "08:00:000", it then saves it as "07:00:000". If time fields have no time zones, the 'Z' should either not be required or should have no bearing. Thanks for your time though

Comment: If you look at the documentation on Salesforce I linked to, including `Z` will force the timezone to be GMT.

Comment: I understand that. However, what I was trying to point at that if i omit the Z while sending, then Salesforce is storing it as GMT. So, the booking is done in BST at lets say 10:00:00, if i send it as 10:00:00 (without the Z), salesforce then stores it as 09:00:00Z and then on the detail page show it as 09:00 instead of 10.  Thats my confusion. If time fields have no timezone why is it not mapping 10 as 10.